# Unbounded sequence has an divergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that if $(x_n)$ is unbounded, then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim 1/(x_{n_k}) =0.$

I was thinking that $(x_n)$ is a subsequence of itself. WLOG, suppose $(x_n)$ does not have an upper bound. By Algebraic Limit Theorem, $\lim 1/(x_{n_k}) =0.$

Is there any flaws in my proof?

Comment: Consider the sequence $1,2,1,4,1,8,1,16,\ldots$. The reciprocals of this sequence has no limit. Not to mention that it can even contain 0.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have a subsequence such that

$$a_{n_{1}}>1$$

$$a_{n_{2}}>2$$ and so on such that $$a_{n_{k}}>k$$ which is justified as $a_n$ is unbounded. Thus you get a subsequence which diverges to infinity as $k\rightarrow \infty$.